# How to render partial view to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

How to call `Html.Partial()` method from controller or some other method in external class library?

I need something like:

```
string someView = "SomeView";
object someModel = new SomeModel();    
HtmlHelper helper = new HtmlHelper();    
string html = helper.Partial(someView, someModel).ToString();
```

I need to get html string which this method returns.

Comment: Pretty sure you are doing something wrong. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: So, what you want is to be able to use the Razor engine on a template outside of a view?

Comment: I don't need to use Razor engine. Only System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper class methods outside mvc project.

Comment: Not sure you understand what `Partial()` does, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to render partial view to string you can use this link: [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

But i think you doing something wrong...

Answer (score 2):

you need to use WebClient for download the html page, something like that:

```
string viewUrl = Url.RouteUrl(new { Controller = "Pages", Action = "Index" });

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
string result = client.DownloadString(new Uri(viewUrl ));
```

then you will get the page's html